# How to retrive images from Local Drive and display in views in MVC4?

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all i am working on application where users uploads images and i am saving those images in my local folder in a local drive not on server and i am saving that url in my db

```
 if (UploadedImages != null )
        {
            var img = 0;
            foreach (var Image in UploadedImages)
            {                   
                if (Image.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(Image.FileName);
                    var path = System.IO.Path.Combine("D:\\SCommerceImages\\", fileName);

                    Image.SaveAs(path);
                    if (img == 0)
                    {
                        customProduct.ThumbNailImage = ".." + path;
                        img++;
                    }
                    else if (img == 1)
                    {
                        customProduct.BigImage = ".." + path;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewData["Image"] = ".." + path;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

my porblem is that when i try to retrieve those images,the images are not displayed in my view when i check them using firebug it says failed to load the image can any one tell me how can i overcome this problem

Answer (score -1):

Change your

`var path = System.IO.Path.Combine("D:\\SCommerceImages\\", fileName);`

to

```
 var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"D:\SCommerceImages\", fileName.extension);
```

Comment: Still the same issue ia hve this url in my src when i see in firebug "@D:\SCommerceImages\2go-logo.jpg"

Comment: hey, you must nt be able to see @ in Firebug...Have you stripped double slashes from your former code just I have done?

Comment: @SoftwareNerd: NOtice that I have put @ outside of the string